# Allow duplicates as a viable option

Tags: discussion, duplicate-suggestions

Sometimes there arise moments when you feel you need to open a duplicate. For instance, as technology evolves, correct answers of the duplicate questions may become outdated or better answers might exist as a result of new features of that technology.

Wouldn't it be beneficial if we could just create duplicate questions to get more recent and most probably *more efficient* answers. I am well aware that it is a tough task to force people not post "outdated" answers. I posted this to trigger a brainstorming activity in hope of someone coming up with a brighter idea to address the issue.

**Update:** If I am the OP, I can easily remove the correct answer to draw more attention, but if I am not I need to create a new question which will be closed since it will be a duplicate. Post Your Answer is not a possibility since the motive of all this is that I don't know the answer.

Comment: See that **edit** link under the question?

Comment: See that form with a **Post Your Answer** button at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Point being - you can edit a question to make it more relevant/current (so long as you don't change the meaning of the answers). You can also add an answer with the current practice, explaining why the other answers are no longer viable/correct/best practice and what makes them outdated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is called bounties.

Comment: @Oded I feel I am well aware of the community rules and features and of course I can **see** those two buttons. I think there is no need to be harsh on people with low reputation. Updated the question specifically to answer your questions.

Comment: I was being factual - possibly abrupt with those two first comments. But my point was that you _can_ address the issues directly on the question. How? Adding comments. Suggesting an edit (or making one directly, if you have the reputation) to bring it up to date. Post a bounty to get attention to the question, explaining why the bounty has been offered on it (i.e. bring up-to-date answers to the question). A Duplicate amnesty is not needed and would only be confusing and harmful (because if it is an option, everyone with a dup will use it).

Answer (score 8):

NO Please,

Do not duplicate questions. If you feel answers on a particular question are outdated or not efficient enough. You can add your own answer, comment on the existing answers or preferrably add a bounty on the question stating what you want

Answer (score 3):

You can ask a similar question but not a duplicate. Say you find an old C++ question and you think the answers are outdated now that C++ 11 (and soon 14) have come along. You can:

- add your own answer that mentions the specific new language features and is generally a better answer than any that was there before
- ask a new question, linking to the old one, that asks "does anything in C++ 11 change this?" (careful not to be too open-ended or opinion seeking though)
- ask a new question, linking to the old one, that asks "what has changed in the last 5 years that might invalidate these old answers?" (same caveat as above)
- add a bounty to the old question and explain in your reasoning that you want a more up to date answer than what is there.
- comment on each possibly outdated answer asking if it is still true in 2013, or if you know it's not, commenting that it is now outdated

Which is the right strategy depends on how much you already know. If you have no clue whether anything has changed or not, whether those answers are outdated or not, then the bounty is probably good. If you're sure the answers are outdated but don't know the current answers, the carefully worded linked question is probably good. And if you know the current state of affairs, add an answer of your own. Consider bountying the question for attention - I typically get back the whole bounty in upvotes when I do that - or promoting it on twitter etc to attract a new set of answerers.